# Django rest framework foreign key pointing to different tables

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework, Models and serializers.
I have three different types of tables.

1. chatrequest
2. videorequest
3. audiorequest

I have another table notifications where I will be storing notification related to that table
It has the following fields

1. message
2. request_id (Foreign key)
3. request_type (chatrequest, videorequest, audiorequest)

What I am trying to do is that based on request_type, request_id details get fetched from the primary table.

Notification model

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name ='users_id',
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True )
request_type = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
request_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Notification serializer

```
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = userSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'message', 'request_id', 'request_type')
```

Comment: What kind of detail information you want to be fetched ?

Comment: I want to get complete primary model, otherwise I will to add a separate query to get that.

Comment: A generic foreign key might work here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations. DRF has documentation on how to support generic relations in your serializers https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships